# Adding lightbox image's on image maps

Tags: html, lightbox, imagemap

I'm struggling to find any real awnser or tutorial on how to do this, is there anyway to actually point the coordinates to different parts of the image map and when clicked load a lightbox image.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I believe either nohref attribute or html5 made this deprecated so make the href a #.

When instantiating the lightbox code some which you can change the source so you could add in the area tags like data-source

Im not positive of what lightbox you're using so anyways give your area tags a class and the attribute I just told you about and use

```
//this is just an example do not use this jQuery   
$('.lightbox').Lightbox ({
     source: this.getAttribute ('data-source'),
  });
```

Html

```
<area shape="rect" coords="coordinates" data-source="images source" class="lightbox" href="#">
```

To stop page jump return false or e.preventDefault() in the listener. Sorry im on my phone or else I'd explain a whole lot better. Hopefully you get what I mean.